# Search matching transaction code from browser

Tags: browser, sap-gui

If I need a matching transaction code (TCode) for the thing which I want to do in SAP I often google for the matching tcode. Usually I can find a matching tcode quickly, then I enter it in the well known input in the upper left corner of the SAP GUI.

Is there a way to avoid the switching between browser and SAP GUI?

Is there a way to search for the matching tcode by its description?

For example I search a tcode to list all available users in the system.

Answer (score 1):

use Table **TSTC** or database view **INFO_TRANT** in order to find **TCODE**, the description can be found in TTEXT field.